# Endless scrolling on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm having some trouble implementing endless scrolling for a list in my jQuery Mobile application. The code i am using now is this:

```
$(window).on('scrollstop', function () { 
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 20) {
    if(scrollLoad && currentPage < totalPages)
    {
      $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
      ShowMoreThings();
      scrollLoad = false; //Is set to true on ajax success in ShowMoreThings().
    }
  }
});
```

This however does not cause the refresh to always trigger. The problem seems to be that the event triggers as soon as the user releases the screen, and the viewport keeps moving after this (due to the way scrolling usually works on mobile devices). The event will then calculate the position while it is still moving and not trigger the refresh since it has not reached the bottom. And then, with the viewport now at the bottom of the page, no further scroll events are triggered if the user tries to scroll further down as the viewport doesn't move. To trigger it, i need to scroll slightly up and then down again.

I tried listening to scrollstart too, but it doesn't trigger attempting to scroll into "nonexistant space".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some experimenting and trying other solutions it seems there was a simple and rather obvious solution to the problem. If i increased the margin for scrolling, ie the 20 pixels from the question to 200 it will always trigger, no matter the speed of the scrolling or if i release the screen before it has reached within 200 pixels of the bottom of the page.

I have no idea when the event triggers or why it works. Either way, it works now, and having a larger margin than 20 is probably better anyway since it begins loading new content before the user has seen all the existing content.

Comment: Is that because status bar and menu bar are included in `$(window).height()`?

Comment: I don't think so. Because it did work with 20px marginal, but only if i scrolled down slowly. This i guess gave the event time to trigger during the 20px interval.

Answer (score 1):

I find it more reliable to use the `onscroll` event to bind my endless scrolling in jquery mobile.

Comment: Explanation: If the scrolling hasn't stopped, you won't trigger the 'scrollstop' event; you need to bind to something else to trigger before the scrolling stops.

Comment: This gives the exact same behaviour as the solution with scrollstop i'm already using. It triggers if i scroll slowly enough, but not if i speed down the list.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery waypoints http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/. You can use the waypoint to trigger a fetch of more data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This solution seems like it should work, i couldn't really make it work in a satisfactory manner though. Also, i'd prefer not to use more plugins than necessary, and this should be possible without the use of this plugin.